# Relating the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of a symmetric matrix to the determinants of its principal submatrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I've been thinking about this this problem:

*Let $M$ be a symmetric matrix. Recall that the eigenvalues of $M$ are the  roots of the characteristic polynomial of M:*

$p(x) := det(xI-M) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^n (x-\mu_i)$

*Write*

$p(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n x^{n-k} c_k (-1)^k$

*Prove that*

$c_k = \sum\limits_{S \subseteq [n], |S|=k} \det(M(S,S)). $

*Here, we write $[n]$ to denote the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$, and $M(S,S)$ to denote the submatrix of $M$ with rows and columns indexed by $S$.*

I am a little confused on how to relate the coefficients back to the determinants of submatricies of $M$.

I think it's not too tricky using the product formulation for the characteristic polynomial that the coefficients $c_k$ are the sum of all k-wise products of eigenvalues. Each coefficient $c_k$ then corresponds to the sum of all determinants of principal submatrices of size $k$ for the matrix $\Lambda$ if you write $M = U\Lambda U^T$ via the spectral theorem. Since $U^T = U^{-1}$, $M$ is similar to $\Lambda$. Can you then say that since it is true for the diagonal matrix, it is true of the matrix itself because of similarity? I know the eigenvalues don't necessarily correspond to the respective submatrices of $M$ via Cauchy's interlacing theorem, so it's confusing to me how to jump back to talking about submatrices of $M$.

Or do you need to use some formulation of the determinant to show this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need to think in terms of eigenvalues. Just expand the determinant of $XI_n-M$. In classroom, one teaches that $c_1$ is the trace of $M$, and $c_n$ is its determinant ; these are special cases of the general formula. By the way, you don't need neither symmetry nor real coefficients. This is a purely combinatoric property.

Comment: I think this seems pretty clear to me now - take the permutation definition of determinant, fix $k$ positions in the product corresponding to those on the diagonal to correspond to $x^k$, then (hand waving here using distributive property) ignore all terms from the sum that correspond to other powers of $x$ or constant terms, and you get the formula for the determinant of the principal minor that remains after fixing those $k$ parameters. Do this for all $k$ and you get what you should, and via distributive property all the loose constant terms correspond to $\det(-M)=(-1)^n \det(M)=(-1)^nc_n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The detour through the eigenvalues will not help.
Using the notations of your link, recall that $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and let $M(S,T)$ denote the matrix obtained from $M$ by only keeping the rows with index in $S$ and columns with index in $T$. The the first thing you need is
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial M_{ij}}{\rm det}(M)=(-1)^{i+j}\ 
{\rm det}(\ M(\ [n]\backslash\{i\},\ [n]\backslash\{j\}\ )\ )
$$
which follows from the expansion with respect to say the $j$-th column.
Then, express the $c_k$'s as derivatives at zero of the characteristic polynomial. Finally, compute these derivatives using the multivariate chain rule and the formula above.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm doing this right: first evaluating at x=0 you get $det(-M)$ which is just $(-1)^n det(M)$ which corresponds to $c_n$, then take the derivative and you get the sum of the $n-1 \times n-1$ principal minors of $(xI-M)$ which evaluated at 0 gives the sum of the $n-1 \times n-1$ principal minors of $-M$. Continuing this you get the sum of all the $n-2\times n-2$ minors with appropriate (-1) factor and dividing by 2 for duplicates and so on dividng by $k!$ where $k$ is the number of derivatives taken. Repeat until its just the trace and then n! on the highest order.

Comment: Yes. To do this properly you might want to write a precise formula for the successive derivatives to be proved by induction.